# Expectation of Infinite Sum of Indicator Functions

Tags: probability, limits, probability-theory, measure-theory, expected-value

This is a question for the interchange of a limit and an expectation, in the special case where the random variable of interest is an infinite sum of indicator functions.

Given,
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{i=0}^{t}{1}(A_i)\right]=c < \infty
$$
where $1(\cdot)$ is the indicator function, $A_i$ is some event. What additional conditions (if any) are required to guarantee that the limit and the expectation operator may be interchanged, such that it holds that
$$
\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}[\sum_{i=0}^{t}\mathbb{P}(A_i)]=c 
$$

Comment: The expressions are not well defined, i.e. $\sum_{i\ge 0}1(A_i)$ and  $\sum_{i\ge 0}\mathbb{P}(A_i)$ do not depend on $i$.

Comment: sorry for the lapse, i do assume though that it should have been obvious what was intended.

Answer (score 1):

Because the indicator functions are non-negative then you can use the [monotone convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem#Beppo_Levi's_monotone_convergence_theorem_for_Lebesgue_integral) to exchange expectation and summation sign.